# Installing node canvas on OSX I get warnings, why is this?

Tags: node.js, macos, canvas

I guess an official package should be stable and not throw compile warnings, so maybe I have the wrong version of something?

Specs:
- OSX 10.8.5
- Xcode 5.1.1
- node 4.2.4
- npm 2.14.12

```
$ npm install canvas --save-dev
-
> canvas@1.3.7 install /Users/petruza/Source/Misc/test/electron-quick-start/node_modules/canvas
> node-gyp rebuild

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/canvas-postbuild.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Canvas.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasGradient.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasPattern.o
In file included from ../src/CanvasPattern.cc:10:
../src/CanvasPattern.h:23:9: warning: private field '_width' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
    int _width, _height;
        ^
../src/CanvasPattern.h:23:17: warning: private field '_height' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
    int _width, _height;
                ^
2 warnings generated.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/color.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Image.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/ImageData.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/init.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/FontFace.o
In file included from ../src/FontFace.cc:7:
../src/FontFace.h:27:15: warning: private field '_ftFace' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
    FT_Face   _ftFace;
              ^
1 warning generated.
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/canvas.node
canvas@1.3.7 node_modules/canvas
└── nan@2.2.0
```

Comment: Those warnings are harmless, and the developer seems to give them low priority (for which I can't blame them): https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/267

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those warnings mean that the developer was just careless about style. I wouldn't regard anything on `npm` as official, as long as it is not backed by any foundation or a company. Just ignore those warnings.